# How can I save and read a special directory path in an XML with vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, filesystems, special-characters

just a quick question: How can I save/read special path like

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "Folder\AnotherFolder"
```

into an **XML file**? I managed to save the string as it is into the XML File in this format:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments &amp; &#34;\Folder\AnotherFolder\&#34; &amp;
```

And it reads perfectly back into my app, but I want to use it as a path inside my code and it won't work throwing me an Exception:

```
New Exception: "System.ArgumentException" in mscorlib.dll
ERROR: Illegal character in Path
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: based on what i see...it looks like the ampersand is part of your file inside a string...rather than doing  the string concatentation...you should show the same code though

Comment: That's not a string. What you should save should not include the `&amp` or `&#34` characters. `myStr = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "Folder\\AnotherFolder"`, and then simply write `myStr` as is to the XML. Let the XML document do any necessary encoding instead of doing it yourself. When reading back, just assign it to a string variable the way the XMLReader gives it to you and let it hand any decoding as well. The ampersand and quotes are not part of your string, so you shouldn't be touching them at all in either direction.

Comment: You should create a path from multiple partial paths using `Path.Combine`, e.g. `Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Folder\AnotherFolder")`. No double backslashes because the backslash is not an escape character in VB but, as suggested, you then store the value of that variable into the XML, not the VB code that constructs it.